# dynamically Adding buttons to a Tab Control context at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm in an MVVM environment and i'm trying to add content to my tab items.  My tab items are generated dynamically and those are working fine.  In attempts to simplify this i have a dictionary that stores a string as a key (tab item header) and a list (currently buttons (i know breaks mvvm and i want to get away from breaking the mvvm pattern)).  I want my buttons to be placed in my item context in the appropriate grid row/column.  I've looked at data templets (how i have my dictionary key mapped to my tab item header), but not sure how to extract the button object from the list.  Binding to the values returns the list properties, not the button properties.

My first question would be how to put a button in a tab control context stored in a list at runtime.
My second question would be how to determine which grid row/column it should go in.  I would like to make it true(er) MVVM and use the data template triggers but for now i have the min width/height set to store the grid row/column it should be contained in.

Here's what i got so far:

```
<TabControl Margin="10,10,10,26" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding FUGU}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
...
</TabControl>
```

C# view model

```
public Dictionary<string, List<Button>> FUGU{ get; set; }
//inside constructor
foreach(var item in Items)
        {
            if (!Categories.Contains(item.Category))
            {
                Categories.Add(item.Category);
                List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
                int row = 0;
                int col = 0;
                foreach (var i in Items.FindAll(x => x.Category == item.Category))
                {
                    Button btn = new Button() { Content = i.Name, Tag = i.SKU, MinWidth=col, MinHeight=row };
                    buttons.Add(btn);
                    if(row==10)
                    {
                        row = 0;
                        col += 1;
                    }
                }
                FUGU.Add(item.Category, buttons);
            }

        }
```

Edit:
so i've made some changes and created an object and found the ItemsControl class.  here is my updated code:

```
<TabControl Margin="10,10,10,26" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding FUGU}" Background="#FFE5E5E5">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>


                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Value}" >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <Grid x:Name="grid">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Button Content="{Binding content}" Tag="{Binding tag}" Grid.Row="{Binding gridRow}" Grid.Column="{Binding gridCol}" Margin="5" FontSize="31"/>

                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>


            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

C# view model

```
foreach(var item in Items)
        {
            if (!Categories.Contains(item.Category))
            {
                Categories.Add(item.Category);


                List<POSButtonInfo> btnInfoLst = new List<POSButtonInfo>();
                int row = 0;
                int col = 0;
                foreach (var i in Items.FindAll(x => x.Category == item.Category))
                {
                    btnInfoLst.Add(new POSButtonInfo { content = i.Name, tag = i.SKU, gridCol = col, gridRow = row });


                    if(row==9)
                    {
                        row = 0;
                        col += 1;
                    }
                    else
                        row+=1;
                }
                FUGU.Add(item.Category, btnInfoLst);
            }

        }
```

the bindings in my button in are from my custom object.  These bindings work fine however, i'm getting some unexpected behavior such as in my view, the buttons don't respect the grid, by that i mean i have 10 row definitions and created 12 test objects to put into my view.  As you can see in the code that when 9 is hit (10th element) that it should go to the next column and start over at 0.  Instead it goes to the next column, but doesn't reset the 0th row.  Also the button objects to not take up the entire column and when looking in the design view, only the first row of the grid appears as opposed to the normal view of the entire grid.  I'm new to data templates so i'm sure i'm doing something wrong.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you take a Dictionary<string, Grid>> instead of Dictionary<string, List<Button>> ???

Comment: if i wanted to go that route, i could just do a user control, but i would like a solution that is more MVVM geared

Comment: you end up in one tabitem with 10items with 10 grids for each item. is that what you really want?

Answer (score 0):

what i would do is the following. within my mainviewmodel i would create a list with my tabitemviewmodels

```
public List<ITabItemViewmodel> MyTabContent {get;private set}
```

then i would fill this list with viewmodels i wanna show in this tab eg.

```
 MyTabContent.Add(new NameVm());
 MyTabContent.Add(new AdressVm());
 MyTabContent.Add(new OtherVm());
```

a tabviewmodel could look like this

```
 public class NameVm : ITabItemViewmodel
 {
    public string HeaderText {get;set;}

    public ICommand MyCommand {get;set;}

    //other properties and stuff
 }
```

and if i have such nice tabitemviewmodel i can simply use DataTemplates to let wpf render my view

```
 <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyTabContent}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <!-- this is the header template-->
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderText}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

anywhere in your Resources you should of course define DataTemplates for your "TabItemViews"

```
<DateTemplate DataType="{x:Type NameVm}">
 <view:MyViewForNameVm/>
<DataTemplate>
```

sample view

```
 <UserControl x:class="view:MyViewForNameVm">
   <!-- here are all my Controls with bindings for my NameVm-->
   <Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
 </UserControl>
```

Comment: I want to try to stay away from have UI content in my view model.  My updated code (bottom 2 code blocks) sucessfully puts data into my tabitem content but it doesn't respect the grid.

Comment: ?? i dont have any ui stuff in my viewmodel. why you think that?

Comment: Your right i misread the classes (need sleep).  How is this different from what i have now?  I have a class that gets my button's content, grid row/col position tag.  I can create everything i need,  i don't want to put grid and other UI in my VM  so how do i get my XAML to respect the information sent to it?  The POSButtonInfo class that i have a list of is my object holding UI data information to properly format it.  The buttons just aren't rendering as i would expect.

Comment: you should really read some more blogs about mvvm. look at my little sample. i dont have any ui code within my viewmodels (you have eg Button class) further more i create all VIEWS(for all TabItems) in XAML with bindings. My viewmodels in the MyTabContent  Property are bind to the TabControl and rendered by wpf through the DataTemplates.

Comment: and i agreed with you that you do not have any UI classes in your VM.  from my understanding i am already doing what you suggested, but on a smaller scale.  My question is how to make my XAML respect my grid position data in my class posted in the update.